# How to convert Array of arrays to hash in perl with tags inside?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I think i've seen all the posts on this topic, but couldn't find my case, or modify something to match my case, that's why i ask here...

My files are like :

```
my @tab1;
A 12 15 48 63 -5 ...
T 45 8 96 31 1123 ...
G 458 96 22 36 54 ...
C 45 1 32 1 6 ...
```

`...` for continuing with a lot of numbers.

I managed to obtain the other configuration ;

```
my @tab;
A T C G
12 45 458 45
15 8 96 1
48 31 22 32
63 31 36 1
-5 1123 54 6
... ... ... ...
```

And i want to convert one of thoose to hash,

With A, T, G, C as tags, 
And each values at it's position.

Like if i call

`%Hash [T,5]` 
(or [T,4] if hash values starts at 0 i don't know the propre call for it)

It gives me 1123

I don't know how to call it yet, if you can give me hints =).

Maybe i'm trying to get hash of hashes from array of arrays... 
I'm not sure, my brain overheated...

Thank you for reading me and for trying to help.
It sound to me like an easy problem, but i'm stuck on that...

Ps : Geting 4 hash is ok too. 
One for each letter... 
Maybe `map` can help, but i got problems using it, i can't find the good arguments...

PPS :

As asked, i'll clarify this.

My input is :

I use :

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings; 
use Array::Transpose;
use Text::CSV;
```

A csv file :

```
A;T;G;C
-3;4;-1;1
0;12;-13;-9
-7;4;-9;-10
-6;8;-9;-17
-5;4;-6;-19
-7;13;0;-6
-22;23;4;-17
-5;0;-18;-16
0;0;-9;-7
4;12;-16;-24
-13;13;1;-12
-9;19;5;-21
-3;0;-12;-12
-2;22;-4;-26
[...][...][...][...]
```

`[...]` continues, but same number of values for each column.

Which from i extract datas with :

```
    my @tabab1;
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ';' });
    my $ligne=0;
    open my $fhand, '<', "$ARGV[2]/sortie.csv" or die "Soucis d'ouverture de : $ARGV[2]/sortie.csv $!";

    while( my $ligne = $csv->getline( $fhand ) ) { 
        #shift @$ligne;       
        push @tabab1, $ligne;
    }
print "@{$tabab1[0]}\n"; 
print "@{$tabab1[1]}\n";
print "@{$tabab1[2]}\n";
print "@{$tabab1[3]}\n";
```

It gives me this :

```
A T G C
-3 4 -1 1
0 12 -13 -9
-7 4 -9 -10
```

If i reverse it, with :

```
my @tabab;
my $l; #ligne
my $c; #colone

for $l (@tabab1) {
  for $c (0 .. $#{$l}) {
    push(@{$tabab[$c]}, $l->[$c]);
  };
};
for my $l2 (@tabab) {
  for my $c2 (@{$l2}) {
  };
};

print "@{$tabab[0]}\n"; #cliquer dessus pr afficher, bug... 
print "@{$tabab[1]}\n";
print "@{$tabab[2]}\n";
print "@{$tabab[3]}\n";
```

i get this :

```
A -3 0 -7 -6 -5 -7 -22 -5 0 4 [...]
T 4 12 4 8 4 13 23 0 0 12 13 1 [...]
G -1 -13 -9 -9 -6 0 4 -18 -9 [...]
C 1 -9 -10 -17 -19 -6 -17 -16 [...]
```

I can't copy the whole lines, it's about 950 values that's why i wrote `[...]`

There is the same number of values in each row/lane and only 4 letters

My goal is to get one of thoose two in hash. 
With first key A, T, C, and G, and second key, the position of the value. 1st, 2nd, to the last one.

Like a grid with in one axe my 4 letters, and on the other, the position.

```
1st key : A   T   C   G
    1st  -3   4   1  -1
    2nd   0  12  -9 -13
    3rd  -7   4  -10 -9
    4th ... and it continues
Position is the second key.
```

To be able to call a value by calling the letter and the postion.

Or 4 hashes, one for each lettre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you edited question using `csv` file you could add values to hash of arrays directly when reading the csv file, without the transposing:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 } );
open my $fh, "<", "gene.csv" or die "gene.csv: $!";
$csv->header( $fh, { munge_column_names => 'none'} );

my @colnames = $csv->column_names;
my $HoA;
while( my $row = $csv->getline_hr($fh) ) {
    push @{$HoA->{$_}}, $row->{$_} for @colnames;
}
my $ret = $csv->getline_all($fh);
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;

say "The second val from the 'T' column: $HoA->{T}[1]";
say "Dump of the whole ", Dumper $HoA;
```

So, for the example `gene.csv`

```
A;T;G;C
-3;4;-1;1
0;12;-13;-9
-7;4;-9;-10
-6;8;-9;-17
-5;4;-6;-19
```

will print:

```
The second val from the 'T' column: 12
Dump of the whole $VAR1 = {
          'G' => [
                   '-1',
                   '-13',
                   '-9',
                   '-9',
                   '-6'
                 ],
          'T' => [
                   '4',
                   '12',
                   '4',
                   '8',
                   '4'
                 ],
          'C' => [
                   '1',
                   '-9',
                   '-10',
                   '-17',
                   '-19'
                 ],
          'A' => [
                   '-3',
                   '0',
                   '-7',
                   '-6',
                   '-5'
                 ]
        };
```

Comment: "directly when reading the csv file, without the transposing"
That sound even better XD ! 

I try it now !

Comment: It works perfectly  ! 
Can u explain to me binary and auto_diag in Text::CSV ?

And 'munge_column_names' ?

Thank you for you time @jm666

Answer (score 4):

Your question is hard to understand, but I think that's a language problem. So what I believe you are trying to say is that you have a file with data like this:

```
A 12 15 48 63 -5
T 45 8 96 31 1123
G 458 96 22 36 54
C 45 1 32 1 6
```

And you would like to access it using a data structure like a table (called a *hash-map* in many technologies), where the first level has the letter, and the second level is an array of values.

In Perl, that could look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $data;
while (my $row = <DATA>) {
    chomp $row;
    my ($key, @values) = split /\s/, $row;
    $data->{$key} = [ @values ];
}

CORE::say $data->{T}->[4]; # first index is 0

print Dumper $data;

__DATA__
A 12 15 48 63 -5
T 45 8 96 31 1123
G 458 96 22 36 54
C 45 1 32 1 6
```

Let's look at what this does.

- The [`__DATA__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) is to simulate reading from a file. You can `open` an actual file and read from the file handle instead.
- `$data` will hold our data structure
- You need to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) each line to remove the trailing newline
- You [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) on whitespace, and the first value is the letter
- You build the data structure. The `$key` is the letter, and the values go into an array reference.

This program will output two things.

```
1123
```

That's what you were looking for. Because arrays in Perl are zero-indexed, `$data->{T}->[4]` gives you the 5th value.

The `{T}` indicates that there is a *hash reference*. That's an associative array, or a hash map, or simply something where you access it by *name*. Those structures are not ordered.

The `[4]` indicates that there is an *array reference*. That means there is a list of values that are ordered. It starts with index `[0]`.

You were talking about `map`, but you don't really need that here. As you can see, the program to read that data is quite simple without a `map`.

Then we have the debug output using [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper). It shows

```
$VAR1 = {
          'T' => [
                   '45',
                   '8',
                   '96',
                   '31',
                   '1123'
                 ],
          'A' => [
                   '12',
                   '15',
                   '48',
                   '63',
                   '-5'
                 ],
          'G' => [
                   '458',
                   '96',
                   '22',
                   '36',
                   '54'
                 ],
          'C' => [
                   '45',
                   '1',
                   '32',
                   '1',
                   '6'
                 ]
        };
```

For more information, see [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html). Maybe also [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html).

Comment: That definitly looks like it. 

Yes i couldn't even find my keyword to find the question.


 You call that a hash table ? ... 

I try it and come back, than you...

Comment: "You need to chomp each line to remove the trailing newline"
Do i have to do it since it's an array ?
Aren't the spaces only when printing it ?

I updated my original post with more détails, can you look at it quickly ?

"$data->{T}->[4]; # first index is 0"
That is good, i don't have to set a secondary key then. 

"hash map, or simply something where you access it by name"
Technical terms you know. Excellent ^^. 

"As you can see, the program to read that data is quite simple without a map."
Yes, it looks simple. It was more a thinking problem than a technical one.

Thank you.

Comment: @JawharAredsgfs I was assuming a text file. You already have Text::CSV to read your file, so that's great. You don't need to bother about chomping and splitting. The important part of the answer is the data structure anyway. The rest is just to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you again for your help simbabque.
I did this :     
'my $hashab1;
while (my $l3 = @tabab) {
    chomp $l3;
    my ($cle3, @valeurs3) = split /\s/, $l3;
    $hashab1->{$cle3} = [ @valeurs3 ];
}

print $hashab1->{T}->[4]; # first index is 0'

But not working, i guess i'm not using it well,
How to use an array in place of  '<DATA>'

Comment: @JawharAredsgfs the other answer makes more sense, if you already use Text::CSV anyway.

Comment: Yep, i saw that, it works, thank you anyway @simbabque.
It wasn't clear on my original post, my bad.